# Why does factoring x out of a square root change the sign of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So my question is the following: why does $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-2x^3\sqrt{-x+x^2}}{5x^4} = \frac {2}{5}$$
while
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-2x^4\sqrt{\frac{-1}{x}+1}}{5x^4} = \frac {-2}{5}$$
~ in other words, why does factoring another x out of the square root change the sign of the limit? I was trying to solve for the $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{G(x)}{\sqrt{(-x)^5}}$, where *G* is a primitive of $f(x):(-\infty, 0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) =x\sqrt{1-x}$. I decided to use l'Hôpital's rule and thus arrived at this dilemma.

Comment: $\sqrt {x^{2}}$ is not $x$. It is $|x|$.

Comment: Hah, that was such a dumb moment by me LOL. Thanks!

Comment: In a neighborhood of $-\infty$ it is $\vert x \vert=-x$